# SAPUI5 App without destination(cloudconnector)

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway

i have a question.. for example i dont want to use the sap cloud and want to deploy my app on a sap gatewayserver so what do i have to change? my app works trough the cloud platform with a destination (cloudconnector).. but i dont want this way anymore. So what i need to change in the manifest or the neo.js? maybe you guys have an example? bc. i dont really find anything what gives me the click in my head..

i dont want to change all the calls to ajax calls.. so there used to be a good solution to change something in the manifest or neo.. or something like that right? so you dont have to change your code

as i said the best way is to show me an example and explain me on this example.

my neo-app.js

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/sap/opu/odata",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "prototyp2",
        "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
      },
      "description": "prototyp2"
    }
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true
}
```

as you can see the last route thats the destination via cloud connector.

and this is my manifest

```
{
    "_version": "1.12.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "test",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "resources": "resources.json",
        "ach": "ach",
        "sourceTemplate": {
            "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponentForManifest",
            "version": "0.0.0"
        },
        "dataSources": {
            "ZEITERFASSUNG_2_SRV": {
                "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/test_SRV/",
                "type": "OData",
                "settings": {
                    "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "icons": {
            "icon": "",
            "favIcon": "",
            "phone": "",
            "phone@2": "",
            "tablet": "",
            "tablet@2": ""
        },
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": true,
            "phone": true
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_hcb",
            "sap_bluecrystal"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "Zeiterfassung.view.timeOverview",
            "type": "XML"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.66.0",
            "libs": {
                "sap.m": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.table": {
                    "minVersion": ""
                },
                "sap.ui.unified": {
                    "minVersion": ""
                }
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
                "settings": {
                    "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                    "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                    "defaultCountMode": "Request"
                },
                "dataSource": "test_SRV",
                "preload": true
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "Zeiterfassung.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "idAppControl"
            },
            "targets": {
                "TargettimeOverview": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "TimeOverview"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.platform.hcp": {
        "uri": "webapp",
        "_version": "1.3.0"
    }
}
```

Thanks guys

:)

Comment: on prem the odata services and the app itself are served out of ICF, so the odata uri in the manifest should reflect that: `resources/whatever/cloudconnector/` to `/sap/opu/odata/sap/my_service_name`. you might need a working index file etc as well since the launchpad uses the component.

Comment: mh i dont know if i am understand you right.. i edited my question with code. Maybe it helps you to get a better way to understand what i want

Comment: should be ok.. have you considered actually deploying it to gateway and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

your neo-app.js is only for the webide.

- Rename your "webapp" folder to "WebContent".
- export your app
- unpack
- use the ui5 uploader in your backend
  "/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD" for uploading

If you run the index.html directly ( instead of using a launchpad), be sure your script-tag in your index.html is set to **src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"**